# Update error that is undefined field name in MySQL and php

Tags: php

I already declared

```
$today=date(Y:m:d H:I:s);
```

While in my updated query: I written as

```
$query=mysql_query("update bookrentalinfo set status="returned" 
                   and actualreturndate=$today where memno=1");
```

Here my aim to update `bookrentalinfo` table with status as returned and `actualreturndate` to current date.

But i m getting error as *$today as undefined field and status updates to 0*.

Please can u mention where I need to rectify this issue.

Comment: You should post the real code and the complete error messages; this is not even valid php / sql.

Comment: Thank you sir for resolving he issues

Comment: Sir then why status updates to 0, if I give it as a  "returned"

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 and actualreturndate=$today
```

to

```
and actualreturndate=`$today`
```

you need to add `'`

**PS: Kindly read down SQL injection, this is vulnerable.**